# DAX calculated column using IF to evaluate value from another table

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I'm using SSAS Tabular, where I have two tables with a 1:n relationship, **Position** and **Transaction**. There is an active 1:n relationship on PositionID

**Position**

```
+------------+------+--------+
| PositionID | Type | Source |
+------------+------+--------+
| C1000      | A    | 1      |
+------------+------+--------+
| C1200      | B    | 2      |
+------------+------+--------+
| C1400      | C    | 1      |
+------------+------+--------+
```

**Transaction**

```
+---------+------------+--------+
| TransID | PositionID | Amount |
+---------+------------+--------+
| 1       | C1000      | 150    |
+---------+------------+--------+
| 2       | C1000      | 200    |
+---------+------------+--------+
| 3       | C1400      | 350    |
+---------+------------+--------+
```

I want to create a calculated column on table **Transaction** which has the following logic:
IF Position[Type]="A" AND Position[Source]<>1 THEN Transaction[Amount] * -1 ELSE Transaction[Amount] * -1

I've tried using the RELATED function in DAX but its not detecting the related Position table; when I type it manually it returns the error "cannot find table":

```
=IF(RELATED(Position[Type]) = 'A' && RELATED(Position[Source]) <> 1;-1*Transaction[Amount];Transaction[Amount])
```

I have no duplicates on the table which is on the 1 side of the 1:n relationship. Should I try a different DAX function?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using LOOKUPVALUE, and so far it looks good.

```
=IF(LOOKUPVALUE(Position[Type];Position[PositionID];Transaction[PositionID])="A"&&LOOKUPVALUE(Position[Source];Position[PositionID];Transaction[PositionID])<>"1";-1*Transaction[Amount];Transaction[Amount])
```